# Libgdx robovm build error

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

I'm trying to run my libgdx app on iOS using robovm it compiles all the classes but at the end it gives me this error.

```
Build failed. Check the RoboVM console for more information.
Cannot run program "2014-05-25 15:22:54.333 xcodebuild[761:d07] [MT] PluginLoading: Required
plug-in compatibility UUID A2E4D43F-41F4-4FB9-BB94-7177011C9AED for plug-in at path
'~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in
DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++":
error=2, No such file or directory
```

I looked and I have that plugin in that location. I already have the newest version of Xcode.

Comment: I am facing same issue. if you fond solution then can you please tell me.

Comment: Update unity game engine.